# AddCors not showing any headers for Access-Control-Allow-Origin ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am a newbie at ASP.NET with my second attempt at coding in .NET, so please be patient with me and thank you for your assistance with the first project. The following project is an attempt to create a .NET API that will only GET JSON for the React app to display datagrids and paginated data.

As the title states, I am not seeing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the header section within the developer tools - see attached screen shot.

[image: json-header within developer tools]

As you can see by the prior screen shot, it is working as expected, except that the headers do not show anything regarding Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which is causing my react app to throw an error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" - when I place the JSON within a file and have the react app retrieve the local .json file, everything works as expected, which confirms, that not receiving the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the headers is the issue. The following code is my Startup.cs file which uses MySql to retrieve the data.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace v2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecific", p => p.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3006")
                                                        .WithMethods("GET")
                                                        .WithHeaders("name")));
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            //MySql
            services.AddTransient<MySqlDatabase>(_ => new MySqlDatabase("server=xyz.com; database=someDB; uid=someUser; pwd=somePwd; port=somePort;"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.EnvironmentName == "dev")
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3006")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                );
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "OrderItem",
                    template: "OrderItem/{div?}/{yr?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "OrderItem", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

To achieve the JSON to appear without any html tags, this was accomplished by having only @ResponseBody in the _Layout and @HTML.raw(JSON.parse(Model)) in the OrderItem/Index.cshtml page.

In PHP, I would use something like the following to show Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the headers:

```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Do I have to do something similar in the _Layout and cshtml pages?

One other point, I will not be able to try out your suggestions until I return to work on Monday, but as usual, thanks in advance and I appreciate your assistance

Comment: The screenshot doesn't prove anything. When you load the URL in the browser like that, it's not a cross-origin request, so there will be no cross-origin headers.

Comment: Thanks for replying @KirkLarkin, but when I looked at the headers in the react app on localhost:3006 - it also displayed a similar header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to add an attribute class, plus have it available to the entire controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace v2
{
    public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3006");

            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Followed by adding this to the OrderItemController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using dto = v2.Models;
using mFilter = v2.AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute;

namespace v2.Controllers
{
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
```

While I did see a similar post with this answer, I was unable to get it to work until I added:

```
using mFilter = v2.AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute;
```

Which made it available for the entire controller, by adding:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
```

underneath the namespace and above the controller class

Sorry no screen shot, I sent an email with the screen shot to myself from work, but the system must have blocked it form arriving.

As usual, thanks in advance and thanks to @KirkLarkin for pointing out that just looking at the headers from localhost:5001 does not prove that it was not responding with the headers that I wanted to see, which lead me to view the headers from the React app's localhost:3006 perspective.